# Why tsc path is not detected(Windows) ? 'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: typescript, windows, npm

When I run(from Gitbash)

```
npm run compile
```

I got

'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

I checked

```
$ npm config get prefix
C:\Users\romanrublev\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

I installed tsc(npm i-g tsc).
In the above directory I have
[image]

I checked env variables on my Windows

[image]

Install again

```
npm install -g typescript
C:\Users\romanrublev\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsc -> C:\Users\romanrublev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsc
C:\Users\romanrublev\AppData\Roaming\npm\tsserver -> C:\Users\romanrublev\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\bin\tsserver
+ typescript@4.4.4
```

Why tsc path is not detected? Maybe multiple npms(global,.npmrc)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a step by step walkthrough for a solution that worked for me. Hope this helps.

[image: Step by step walkthrough]

Comment: If you are copying the solution from somewhere else, you must reference the source. And you should also include the text in the answer instead of a screenshot.